# Formatting fullcalendar js' date display on listMonth view

Tags: javascript, formatting, fullcalendar

I'm currently converting a PSD design that requires the calendar to only display the event day, instead of displaying the full date. e.g. : 12 instead of October 12, 2016

Here's what I have so far:

[image]

As you can see on the left, it displays October 12, 2016. I want it to only display "12". I've tried looking at the docs but I can't find options  specific for listMonth view. And here's my code for the calendar rendering:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,listYear',
            },

            views: {
                listMonth: {
                    titleFormat: 'MMMM'
                }
            },

            defaultView: 'listMonth',

            displayEventTime: false, // don't show the time column in list view

            // THIS KEY WON'T WORK IN PRODUCTION!!!
            // To make your own Google API key, follow the directions here:
            // http://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/
            //googleCalendarApiKey: 'AIzaSyDcnW6WejpTOCffshGDDb4neIrXVUA1EAE',

            // US Holidays
            //events: 'en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com',
                   events: [
    <?php if( $events->have_posts() ) :
        while ($events->have_posts()) : $events->the_post();
            $event_dates = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'date', true);
            $event_info = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'info', true);
            //foreach($event_dates as $event_date):
     ?>
        {

                    title: '<?php the_title(); ?>',
                    start: '<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($event_dates["start_date_time"])); ?>',
                    description: '<?php echo date('ga', strtotime($event_dates["start_date_time"])).', '.$event_info["venue"].', '.$event_info["place"]; ?>'
        },
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
        // more events here
    ],
    eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
        return $('<tr><td>' + event.description + '</td></tr>');
    },


            eventClick: function(event) {
                // opens events in a popup window
                window.open(event.url, 'gcalevent', 'width=700,height=600');
                return false;
            },

            loading: function(bool) {
                $('#loading').toggle(bool);
            }

        });

    });
</script>
```

I hope someone can help me out with this one. That's all I need and then I'm done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use this :

```
$(".fc-list-heading-alt").html($(".fc-list-heading-alt").text().split(" ")[1].split(",")[0]);
```

after calendar is rendered. Hope, this will help you

and also add this onclick in next, prev buttons

Comment: Just tried this. I also tried modifying the text via jquery but it doesn't affect the calendar at all. Any modifications after render doesn't seem to work. But thanks man

Comment: write it after the fullcalendar code i.e. call it when calendar get rendered on the screen

Comment: Have you tried this? I did, it doesn't affect the calendar.

Comment: WHOA, This solved my problem. Thanks man! I had to put it in a separate script. Thanks!

Comment: There's a catch though. Whenever I try navigating to previous and next months, it still displays the full date. Anyway i can fix that?

Comment: @Benedict Payot can you please share your solution?